# Prepending digits to a number

Tags: java, string, numbers

I want to prepend certain digits to a number.  For example, given the number 1234, I want to return 8001234, and given 12345, I want to return 80012345.

My current working solution is `Integer.parseInt("800" + value)`, which involves String formatting, concatenation, and parsing.  I am looking for a somewhat cheaper, easier solution.  (Coming from a C background, this seems expensive.  Java programmers generally don't seem to care about the expense of operations, though, so I might go with this.)

I considered adding 8000000 (or 80000000, 800000000, etc.), but that would depend on the number of digits in the original number, which may vary.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

(Added several months later, Jan. 2014):
As a BTW to this question, my requirements have changed, thus: if the original number is 7 digits, only prepend "80", to keep the new number at a maximum of 9 digits.  I'm not looking for an answer anymore, as I intend to do it the simple, readable way, but I just wanted to throw out the curve-ball addendum to the original question.  Thank you to all who gave helpful suggestions.

Comment: In what way you think your solution is not cheaper? Have you benchmarked it? It looks pretty good.

Comment: @Menachem Search for left padding ...

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization to me.

Comment: @VikasV: Left padding is good for spaces or 0s, not for arbitrary digits (800 in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
int res = 8000 * (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(v) + 1) + v;
```

Comment: I suppose this is what I was looking for, a quick way to determine the length of a number without converting it into a string.  But as others have pointed out, my initial solution reads a lot easier.  So thanks for showing an alternative, but I guess I'll stick with my original (I'm hoping you'd agree, as well).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would avoid going via a string:

```
int value = 1234;
int copy = value;
int toAdd = 8000;
while ((copy /= 10) > 0) toAdd *= 10;
value += toAdd;
```

But I couldn't comment on the performance because I can't be bothered to benchmark it. Personally, I'd go for the maintainable code you had in the question, which is probably performant *enough* for most purposes...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use addition to set the upper bits?

For instance,

```
8000000000 + phone_number
```

This would give you the result you're looking for. Also, from a performance standpoint, integer addition is extremely quick because hardware has specific instructions that can perform the operation is an little as 1 clock cycle.

Comment: I don't have Eclipse here but something like this:

    int value = 1234;
    int toAdd = 8000;
    toAdd = Math.pow(10, (toAdd + "").length());
    value += toAdd;

Comment: Because the length of the value (phone_number in your example) is variable.

Comment: Why not compare the value you have with 1, 10, 100, 1000, ..., etc to determine the number of bits and then append appropriate zeros and use the addition method?

Comment: @bblincoe: Because that would either require a comparison with every possible power of 10.  32 bit numbers, having up to 10 digits, would require 10 comparisons, which loses any performance I would have gained.